# Detox tests do not run on react native android device without reloading the bundle

Tags: android, react-native, detox

I'm trying to run Detox tests on react native android device.

The tests are not running, and detox trace shows "CANNOT_FORWARD:

If in different terminal I start react-native bundle and press "R" for reloading it, the tests start to run.

Attached below trace information:

```
detox[97978] DEBUG: [exec.js/EXEC_CMD, #21] "/Android/sdk/platform-tools/adb" -s emulator-17722 shell "date +\"%m-%d %T.000\""
detox[97978] DEBUG: [exec.js/EXEC_CMD, #22] "/Android/sdk/platform-tools/adb" -s emulator-17722 reverse tcp:64867 tcp:64867
detox[97978] DEBUG: [exec.js/EXEC_CMD, #23] "/Android/sdk/platform-tools/adb" -s emulator-17722 shell "pm list instrumentation"
detox[97978] DEBUG: [exec.js/SPAWN_CMD, #24] [pid=98010] /Android/sdk/platform-tools/adb -s emulator-17722 shell am instrument -w -r -e detoxServer ws://localhost:64867 -e detoxSessionId 2f0e4128-30e3-0737-4ac0-74907e3abed9 -e debug false com.aaa.myWireless.test/androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner
detox[97978] DEBUG: [exec.js/EXEC_CMD, #25] "/Android/sdk/platform-tools/adb" -s emulator-17722 shell "ps | grep \"com\.aaa\.myWireless$\""
detox[97978] DEBUG: [DetoxServer.js/CANNOT_FORWARD] role=testee not connected, cannot fw action (sessionId=2f0e4128-30e3-0737-4ac0-74907e3abed9)
```

Any advice how to get detox to work without the need of manually reloading the bundle.

Also tried:

```
beforeEach(async () => {
    await device.reloadReactNative();
});
```

But it did not help